# Make a game with node.js smoother?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, socket.io

I made a game with `node.js` and uploaded it.. it should be 30 frames per second..
The game is hosted in AppFog. 
Now I testing it and it runs slow.. I mean in local network it runs a lot smoother

I do understand the problem - 
The server is sending a message to the client for every frame, it's basically impossible --
network latencies below 16 ms (60 fps) or 33 ms (30 fps) over the internet are impossible to reliably guarantee. It might work over a local network, and almost certainly can work on a local machine, but not over the internet. If I need to get information from the client to the server and back in the next frame, my round-trip latency needs to be that low, including the processing on both sides. Since both xhr-polling and websockets use TCP, it gets worse because one slow/lost packet will pause everything after it until it finally shows up.

So I am in a pretty bad situation..

The game is set with xhr-pooling like this -

```
io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
```

which use TCP and it's very problematic because one slow/lost packet will pause the game..

So how can I make the game smoother? any ideas? I really want to make it work out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What information would you need to send for every single frame?

Comment: If what you're saying is true, is there any way to test it on a friend/co-workers network who has a faster connection?

Comment: @Bergi Every single frame the server sends all the data of all the players in the game to the client and the client prints it

Comment: 1) Don't use XHR polling, use websockets instead. Theres much smaller overheads per request. You should find your throughout increase *hugely* once you use this. 2) Don't require information each frame. Use interpolation and *guess/predict* the values from each client.

Comment: @JohnnyDiamond08 Sure what i am saying its true.. -_-.. If have a friend with faster connection.. I suppose it's a bit faster but still have lags.

Comment: AppFog has hardware limitations for free accounts. I doubt your hitting any of them, but are there bandwidth limits from AppFog?

Comment: What @Matt said, and a few other possible improvements: 1) if a player isn't moving, don't send repeat location information. 2) if not all players are universally visible at all times, only send information to each client about changes they can see.

Comment: Unfortunately, AppFog [does not support WebSockets](http://feedback.appfog.com/forums/171983-appfog/suggestions/3543100-add-websocket-support-to-node-js). [Nodester](http://nodester.com) is the only PaaS that supports WebSockets. Other providers like Heroku (and AppFog) have been talking about WS support over a year, but it has yet to materialize. In fact, AppFog purchased Nodester last year, ostensibly for the sole purpose of adding its WS support into its main node.js stack, but it has yet to do so.

Comment: @apsillers The server sends an array of the players data(their locations, health and stuff).. to the client.. the client takes that data and prints it to the screen.. and the server sends this data 30 times in a second.